# Contact Form doesn´t send emails

Tags: emails, contact-form

We have a problems with the person who build the web and they don´t response our requests, We recently observe that the contact form from the web contact doesn´t send emails, I never used Joomla i don´t know nothing about this platform, but navigation from the administrator site I have been able to observe a module that they say "Contact Form", but the email are correct, where can be the problem? What can I do to solve or to testing? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the error log?  Do you have the error reporting turned up to the maximum?  The more clues that you give us, the best support we can provide.  If you "don't know nothing about this platform", please take the time to research before asking a question.  Please make answering this question as simple as you can for the 100%-volunteer audience here.

Comment: First of all thanks for response, Where can I find the error reporting? I can´t find nothing about logs in the module interface. Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/how-to-turn-your-error-reporting-to-maximum/#:~:text=Joomla%20offers%20you%20five%20levels,switches%20off%20PHP%20error%20reporting. , https://www.joomlart.com/tutorials/joomla-tutorials/joomla-error-reporting-explained , https://www.joomlabeginner.com/blog/tutorials/63-how-to-enable-error-reporting-in-joomla , https://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog